# How to make a actionlink as Image in Asp.Net MVC4 Razpr View?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

NET MVC4 with Entity Framework. I am trying **Rating control**, for that I am using `@Url.Action`. Now i have to convert action link to star image button. Please anyone give me an idea to getit.

This is my code:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("rated/4", "Rating")">Half</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("rated/5", "Rating")">One</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("rated/6", "Rating")">One and Half</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("rated/7", "Rating")">Two</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("rated/8", "Rating")">Two and half</a>
```

Comment: You should be using `routeValues` to pass your rating value.

Comment: You can try into JS : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846862/rating-in-asp-net-mvc4-entity-framework

Answer (score 8):

You can simply add your image tag before closing `</a>`. see code below:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("rated/4", "Rating")"><img style="border:0;" src="image path" alt="Half"></a>
```

Comment: Yeah I already tried it. But while passing the rated value from view to controller, the value is taken as 4 for the all rating. I mean it's taking first line of rating id. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278694/url-action-parameters) would help you for that.