# How do I add an image in @Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to know how to add a image in `@Html.ActionLink`

The code I have is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("IMAGE","Index","Home");
```

How to replace the IMAGE with an URL where my image is residing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a actionlink as Image in Asp.Net MVC4 Razpr View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007291/how-to-make-a-actionlink-as-image-in-asp-net-mvc4-razpr-view)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`@Url.Action`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor) instead:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'>
   <img src="IMAGE PATH HERE" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have one of 2 options

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" >
    <img src="IMAGE" />
</a>
```

OR add a class and use the class to define the image

```
@Html.Action("Text", "Index", "Home", new {Class = "image-link"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("Action", "Controller")%>"><img src="yourimg.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: This is correct, except for the escaping tags. MVC 4 uses the `@` nugget.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Url.Action on Razor :

```
 <img src="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControlName", new { Model.ImageId })" />
```